# Why are ArcGIS Services Showing Wrong Layer Database Schema?

Tags: arcgis-server

I have never seen this before.   Why do two different layers in an ArcGIS Service show different the database schema of the other?

We have an interesting situation with an ArcGIS Service. We have three different environments. There are two tables as part of a map service that show the schema/fields of the other table when the service is published. They have the same table name, but are on different Oracle database schemas (different ArcSDE table owners).

Oracle 11.2.0.1
ArcGIS Enterprise 10.5
ArcSDE 10.2.1 Versioned tables, with some relationship classes defined.
Federated with ArcGIS Portal 10.5.
The table schemas/fields are reflected correctly in the .mxd used to publish the service. The map service layer numbers are identical in both environments.

For example:

Environment #1 Service has SCHEMA111.MyTable and SCHEMA222.MyTable layers in it. The database tables have different fields defined on them. In development when the service is published it shows the same table schema/fields defined, even though the service shows the correct layer name (different table) in the REST page. In this environment the REST page shows SCHEMA111.MyTable and it correctly reflects the table fields. The service shows SCHEMA222.MyTable correctly in the REST page, however it reflects the fields in SCHEMA111.MyTable.

Environment #2 The exact same behavior occurs, however it is totally reversed! SCHEMA222.MyTable shows correctly in the REST page with the correct fields defined on the table. SCHEMA111.MyTable shows correctly in the REST page but the table has the fields (layers and numbers) from SCHEMA222.MyTable.

To reiterate:

The table names (MyTable above) are the same but in different Oracle database schemas (different ArcSDE table owners). ArcSDE and Oracle do not object to this, but is ArcGIS Server perhaps protesting?

The .mxds are correct and show the correct fields for each layer, but the fields are listed incorrectly on the service layer when it is published, even though it says it is the correct name in the REST page.

Comment: How is this different from [yesterday's question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338946/arcgis-enterprise-service-shows-incorrect-table-schema)?

Comment: Please add this info to your original question.

Comment: Yesterday you hollered at me because I didn't phrase it as a question and said it was a discussion.    I don't know why this is happening.   I thought that was pretty clear the first time, but I re-phrased it specifically and asked the forums, since I can't participate in the forums, per your comment.

Comment: Rephrasing can be done in the original question body through an Edit.  SE requires 20 experience points to participate in chat.